# angular 6 select box add first values as default

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6.

```
<select  class="form-control"  id="requestPerson" 
         [(ngModel)]="addRequisitionss.requestPerson"
         name="requestPerson" #workType="ngModel" required >
    <option  *ngFor="let person of RequestPerson"  >
        {{person.requestedPerson}}
    </option>
</select>
```

When I executed above code output looks like
[image]

I need to display the first name (sadique) of option list as default. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the select is bound by ngModel, you can simply set the 
`addRequisitionss.requestPerson` to have the same value as the first option.

in ts

```
this.addRequisitionss.requestPerson = this.RequestPerson[0] ? this.RequestPerson[0].requestedPerson || '';
```

Also, you must give a `value` attribute to each option

```
<select class="form-control" id="requestPerson" [(ngModel)]="addRequisitionss.requestPerson" name="requestPerson" #workType="ngModel" required >
       <option  *ngFor="let person of RequestPerson"  value="{{person.requestedPerson}}">
             {{person.requestedPerson}}
       </option>
</select>
```

Comment: in ts file when i give (addRequisitionss.requestPerson = RequestPerson[0] ? RequestPerson[0].requestedPerson || '';) this  code it shows error like "[ts] ':' expected. " sot that i changed this code to "(this.addRequisitionss.requestPerson =this. RequestPerson[0].requestedPerson;)"..now it is working

Comment: yeah. missed using this. Good catch